# Check if textboxes contain information in vba Userform (Not a simple as it seems...)

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro that I use to print labels at work and I use a Userform to enter the required informations, but I can't seem to find a piece of info that I need to simplify it.

I have a list of textboxes that have name "ID1" through "ID16". I need to:

1) Verify that that each textbox contains Something

2) If that textbox does contain Something, write it's content in a cell on my worksheet.

Exemple: Is the first 3 textboxes contain a number, I need to transpose these 3 numbers in a list on my worksheet. Same for if it contains 6, 8 or 13 numbers.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you always fill textbox1 first then 2 then 3 etc? Does each textbox have a specific cell connected to it or is it A1->A16?

Comment: `If ID1.Text <> vbNullString Then`? ...what code do you have?

Comment: What I want to do basically is For i = 1 to 16 , If ID(i).text = '' '' then...

Comment: but I don't know how to formulate this, since vba doesn't recognize  ID(i).text...

Comment: Does each textbox have a function or are there 16 equal textboxes? If they are all equal and only there to make 16 different sets of data then you might aswel use one textbox with multiline and you split the string on newline and there is your array with the "ID" values

Comment: If you have `ID1` through `ID16`, you have 16 controls, not an array of controls - you can't iterate with `ID(i)` unless you add all 16 controls to an array, say with `textboxes = Array(ID1,ID2,ID3,ID4,ID5,...,ID16)` and then you can iterate the `textboxes` array and go `If textboxes(i).Text = vbNullString Then`

Comment: Please add your code to the question.

Comment: I found I simpler way: All my textboxes are in a separate frame called "listid", and I loop through all of them with a " For each ctrl in userform1.listid.controls ", it works! Thanks for the advices anyway everyone :P

Comment: How about `For i = 1 to 16`. `If Controls("ID" & i).Text = vbNullString Then`...?

Comment: @OlivierHoude This approach has a downside. Consider a case where you add a button or any other control on the same container (frame).

Comment: @GeniusBriaN he has not answered to anything in the comments, I don't think he cares what we say.

Comment: The boxes won'T change, I'm the only one who's able to program in vba in here so... XD

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like the following:

```
Dim txt As String
For i = 1 To 16
    txt = Controls("ID" & i).Text
    If txt <> vbNullString Then
        ' Whatever you want to do with (txt)
    End If
Next i
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
Dim i As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim frmControl As Control

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

ws.Cells(1, 1).Value2 = "Name"
ws.Cells(1, 2).Value2 = "vbString"
ws.Cells(1, 3).Value2 = "TypeName"
ws.Cells(1, 4).Value2 = "Value"

i = 2
For Each frmControl In UserForm1.Controls
    ws.Cells(i, 1).Value2 = frmControl.Name
    ws.Cells(i, 2).Value2 = VarType(frmControl.Object) = vbString
    ws.Cells(i, 3).Value2 = TypeName(frmControl.Object)
    If TypeName(frmControl.Object) = "IMdcText" Then
        Sheet1.Cells(i, 4).Value2 = frmControl.Text
    Else
        Sheet1.Cells(i, 4).Value2 = "not a text box"
    End If
    i = i + 1
Next frmControl
```

Obviously this is a bit more verbose then you need it to be. Yet, that's only for your understanding and can be easily adapted to suit your needs.